# Como aplicar uma função com "forEach", usando um conjunto de itens pré selecionados pelo seletor estilo Jquery?

Tags: javascript, funções, front-end, seletores

Não sei se consegui ser claro no título, e por isso vou exemplificar. No jQuery, a gente poderia fazer algo como isso para deixar todos os H2 com a cor verde:

```
$('h2').css('color','green')
```

Estou tentando me livrar do jQuery, criando função genéricas baseadas no que mais faço em meu site. Por isso, estava transformar aquele código acima em algo como:

// $$ é meu seletor, para evitar conflitos com jQuery, e está definido como

```
function $$(selector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

// setStyle seria uma função que utilizaria um forEach para percorrer todos os itens que o seletor encontrou (o forEach como está na função não funciona pois precisa de ser "chamado" pelo array)

```
function setStyle(styleName, value){
    forEach(function(x){
        x.style[styleName] = value;
    })
}
```

// É assim que gostaria de realizar a mudança em meu site, porém não vejo como passar os itens do seletor para aquele forEach poder utilizar

```
$$('h2').setStyle('color','green')
```

*** Lembrando que se eu passar o seletor como sendo um parâmetro da função setStyle, eu já resolvo isso, conforme exemplo abaixo. Porém não é a maneira que desejo aplicar.

```
function setStyle(elements, styleName, value){
    elements.forEach(function(x){
        x.style[styleName] = value;
    })
}

setStyle($$('h2'),'color','green')
```

Espero ter conseguido exemplificar de maneira clara, e estou aberto a qualquer mudança sugerida no código que me ajude a poder realizar a ação conforme o exemplo que citei acima.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser criar isso sem utilizar classes, você também pode usar uma abordagem mais dependente de *factory functions*:

Não há nada de errado com as classes. É só um outro exemplo de uso para mostrar que você não está obrigado a usar classes se quiser fazer algo assim.

```js
// API PÚBLICA
// ===========

function $$(selector) {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return create$$Object(Array.from(els));
}

// API PRIVADA
// ===========

function create$$Object(els) {
  return {
    getAll: () => els,
    get: (i) => els[i],
    css: $$css(els)
  };
}

function $$css(els) {
  return function css(prop, value) {
    for (const el of els) {
      el.style.setProperty(prop, value);
    }
    return create$$Object(els);
  };
}
```

Note que a função `$$` cria um objeto `$$Object` (nome arbitrário) através da função `create$$Object`. Esse objeto possui todas as funções que esse "clone" do jQuery deve suportar. Além da função `$$`, as outras funções, como o `$$css` também retornam um novo objeto do mesmo tipo, para permitir o encadeamento de funções.

Exemplo de uso:

```js
// Exemplo:
$$('li').css('color', 'red').css('background-color', 'black');

// API PÚBLICA
// ===========

function $$(selector) {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return create$$Object(Array.from(els));
}

// API PRIVADA
// ===========

function create$$Object(els) {
  return {
    getAll: () => els,
    get: (i) => els[i],
    css: $$css(els)
  };
}

function $$css(els) {
  return function css(prop, value) {
    for (const el of els) {
      el.style.setProperty(prop, value);
    }
    return create$$Object(els);
  };
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Baz</li>
  <li>Qux</li>
</ul>
```

Um exemplo um pouco mais completo:

```js
// Exemplo:
$$('li')
  .filter((li) => parseInt(li.textContent, 10) % 2 === 0)
  .append(' (par)')
  .css('color', 'red');

// API PÚBLICA
// ===========

function $$(selector) {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return create$$Object(Array.from(els));
}

// API PRIVADA
// ===========

function create$$Object(els) {
  return {
    getAll: () => els,
    get: (i) => els[i],
    
    // Manipulação e outros:
    css: $$css(els),
    append: $$append(els),
    filter: $$filter(els)
  };
}

function $$css(els) {
  return function css(prop, value) {
    for (const el of els) {
      el.style.setProperty(prop, value);
    }
    return create$$Object(els);
  };
}

function $$append(els) {
  return function append(html) {
    for (const el of els) {
      el.innerHTML += html;
    }
    return create$$Object(els);
  };
}

function $$filter(els) {
  return function filter(predicate) {
    return create$$Object(els.filter(predicate));
  };
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer utilizar essa função `setStyle` como método, você terá que utilizar a mesma abordagem do `jQuery`: crie uma classe contendo todos esses métodos.

Exemplo:

```
class Selector extends Array {
    constructor(query) {
        super()
        var nodos = document.querySelectorAll(query)
        Object.assign(this, nodos)
    }

    css(propriedade, valor) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this[i].style[propriedade] = valor
        return this
    }
}

function $$(query) {
    return new Selector(query)
}
```

Na classe criada, ele irá armazenar todos os nodos encontrado pela função `querySelectorAll` como propriedades, e com o método `css`, eu faço a iteração sobre essas propriedades e aplico o estilo passado como parâmetro. A função `$$` é apenas um "atalho" para criar uma nova instancia dessa classe.

---

A outra alternativa seria adicionar esses métodos direto na classe `NodeList`

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'css', {
    value(propriedade, valor) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this[i].style[propriedade] = valor
        return this
    }
})
```

Você terá que criar e tratar todos os métodos métodos dessa classe manualmente. Isso realmente é mais interessante do que utilizar uma biblioteca como o jQuery?

Enfim, aqui estão exemplos funcionando:

```js
class Selector extends Array {
    constructor(query) {
        super()
        var nodos = document.querySelectorAll(query)
        Object.assign(this, nodos)
    }

    css(propriedade, valor) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this[i].style[propriedade] = valor
        return this
    }
}

function $$(query) {
    return new Selector(query)
}

function trocarCor() {
    $$('span').css('color', 'red')
}
```

```html
<span>Exemplo</span>
<button onclick="trocarCor()">Clique aqui para alterar a cor</button>
```

```js
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, 'css', {
    value(propriedade, valor) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) this[i].style[propriedade] = valor
        return this
    }
})

function $$(query) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(query)
}

function trocarCor() {
    $$('span').css('color', 'red')
}
```

```html
<span>Exemplo</span>
<button onclick="trocarCor()">Clique aqui para alterar a cor</button>
```

Comment: Eu realmente acho que aconselhar a utilizar a modificação de um protótipo no SOpt não é uma boa ideia. No mínimo um aviso. A "poluição de protótpios" não é uma boa prática e quase sempre deve ser evitada, já que pode trazer alguns problemas.